# non static method 'update' should not be called statically. How I can solve this error?

Tags: php, laravel, api

This is my function.
and i'm getting error in it.Kindly help me solve this error.and also tell me why I'm getting this error.

```
  public function update(Request $request)
        {
            $id = $request->id;
            $grade = Grade::find($id);
    
            $grade = $request->validate([
                'title' => 'required|string',
                'slig' => 'string',
                'description' => 'string',
            ]);
    
            $grade = Grade::update($grade);
    
            return [
                'staus' => 'success',
                'grade' => $grade,
            ];
        }
```

Comment: You need to create an object of that class and then call that function.

Comment: For next time; When you get an error message, always start by search on the error message and you will, in most cases, find plenty of questions/answers.

Comment: Lol is your controller named Grade?

Answer (score 0):

Create an instance first. But I don't think that's the real issue.

```
$newGrade = (new Grade() )->update($grade);

return [
    'status' => 'success',
    'grade'  => $newGrade,
];
```

Try changing your method to as follows:

```
    $grade = Grade::findOrFail($request->id);

    $validatedData = $request->validate([
        'title' => 'required|string',
        'slig' => 'string',
        'description' => 'string',
    ]);

    $grade->update($validatedData);

    return [
        'status' => 'success',
        'grade' => $grade,
    ];
```

Comment: You can drop`$g` variable with `$newGrade = (new Grade() )->update($grade);`

Answer (score 0):

## Instantiating a new class

You are trying to access the class as if it were a Facade. You could possibly change the use statement at the top to prepend Facade. The Laravel way of instantiating the class would either be through dependancy injection where you pass the class to the method parameters

```
public function update(Grade $grade, Request $request) {
    // do stuff with $grade->update()
}
```

or use [Real Time Facades](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/facades#:%7E:text=To%20generate%20a%20real,%3A) or use it the way [JeremyKenedy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73566309/10769775) suggested but by using the app() helper function.

```
app()->make(Grade::class)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your update function is wrong. please try it.

```
  public function update(Request $request)
    {
        $id = $request->id;
        $grade = Grade::find($id);

        $grade = $request->validate([
            'title' => 'required|string',
            'slig' => 'string',
            'description' => 'string',
        ]);

        $grade->update([ 
           'title' => $request->title,
           'slig' => $request->slig,
           'description' => $request->description
        ]);

        return [
            'staus' => 'success',
            'grade' => $grade,
        ];
    }
```